# 2-D array as a value in HashMap

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I'm trying to have a 2-D array as a value corresponding to single key in HashMap.

```
HashMap<String, Integer[][]> hm = new HashMap<String, Integer[][]>();
```

And I have Integer array as

```
Integer[][] sumArray = new Integer[2][4];
for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
  for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
     myArray[i][j] = i+j;

Integer[][] multArray = new Integer[2][4];
for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
  for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
     myArray[i][j] = i*j;
```

And I'm inserting it into HashMap hm.

```
 hm.put("SUM", sumArray);
 hm.put("MUL", multArray);
```

Now the problem is for a given key, I want to display one particular element of an array, not the whole array. (Say) if I give key 'SUM' to `get()` method of `HashMap`, and I want to access the value of element sumArray[0][2] , So How should I proceed to do so? Anybody please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you want `multArray[0][2]` when given `SUM` key?

Comment: Ohh..sorry thats a mistake, It should be `sumArray[0][2]`.

Answer (score 2):

Simple

```
hm.get("SUM")[0][2];
```

would do.

Answer (score 2):

Just write:

```
hm.get("SUM")[0][2];
```

Answer (score 2):

do like this.

```
Integer[][] sum = hm.get("SUM");
System.out.println(sum[0][2]);
```

Comment: Excepted the name "SUM" for your variable in uppercase which is not in java precos, this solution is the cleaner.

Comment: The variable SUM should be declared in small letters according to java naming convention. Otherwise its a clean approach.

Comment: But its a key name, not a variable name, Can't it be in UpperCase? I'm just confirming. Because I know the rules for variable names but I really don't know any specific rules (if there are) for key name.

Comment: @Winn Key could be any object and the object name is better to be small letters according to java naming convention.

Answer (score 2):

`hm.get("SUM")[0][2]` would be working.

Answer (score 0):

Integer value = hm.get("SUM")[0][2]; can also be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

hm.get("SUM");

will return an object of the type you saved . Suppose you have saved a string then this will return string or in case of any foo will return foo you just need to type cast it .

foo a= (foo)hm.get("SUM");